# What should the name of our chat room be?

Tags: discussion, chat

I just used my super awesome mod powers to [rename](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4255154#4255154) our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3060/the-water-cooler) from the predictable and dry "The Workplace" to "The Water Cooler", on a whim. It's a cool name, suggested by [Rarity](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4253131#4253131), and it's a reminder of [the Area51 days](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/whats-the-water-cooler) of the site.

Several other sites have cool names for their main chat rooms, some examples are:

- [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), Programmer's main room,
- [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/179/the-heap), DBA's main room,
- [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/118/root-access), Super User's main room,
- [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge), Gaming's main room,
- [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/mos-eisley), SciFi's main room.

Do you like it? Can you think of a better name? Should I be forever exiled for (ab)using my super awesome mod powers on a whim?

Comment: Flagged for abusing mod powers. I was gonna do that...

Comment: @Rarity Next time don't hesitate ;P

Comment: I vote we flog you from the yard arm... then keep the name.

Comment: @rar Not for the main room, chat room tags only make sense for topic oriented chat rooms, not for the general discussion one.

Comment: That makes sense...but most sites have tags in gen discussion too

Comment: @rar  Click the tags on Root Access and The Bridge, they aren't real tags ;P

Answer (score 14):

Whoever suggested this name is a genius. We should keep it.

Comment: Agreed, I think it's the most sensible name, and it reflects what chat is to the site (a water cooler discussion).

Comment: Absolutely this 100%.

Comment: I was about to suggest **water cooler**... I think it is the best solution. Or perhaps *Coffee Machine*...

Comment: We can call it the Scuttlebutt on Talk Like A Pirate day.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller that or the Wat ***arrrrr*** Cooler

Comment: @Rarity I'm going to act like you didn't leave that comment and walk away ;-)

Answer (score -3):

How about...

**The Lobby**

*(not my best idea ever :P)*